# Positioning a div between two divs

Tags: html, css

I have two `div` elements as below:

```
<div class="div1">
  This is div 1
</div>
<div class="div2">
  This is div 2
</div>
```

With `css` as:

```
.div1 {
  border-style: solid;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.div2 {
  border-style: solid;
  margin-left: 50%;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

I want to add a third div which has nothing but a symbol through css.

```
<div class="div3">
</div>
```

with css:

```
.div3:after {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f100";
    color: blue;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

For this to nicely position between the two original `div`'s, I changed `div` 2's css to:

```
.div2 {
  border-style: solid;
  margin-left: 51%;
  padding-left: 6px;
}
```

This looks ok on FullScreen. However, when I minimize the browser window to a smaller size, `div2` starts overlapping `div3`.

How can I nicely position `div3` between `div1` and `div2` with even space at both sides of `div2`?

Here's the JSFiddle for my try: https://jsfiddle.net/d8nuw2m3/5/

Edit:

The flex solution provided below by Roy works fine. However, assume that the content of left and right div's grows a lot. In which case, scroll bar will appear. What if in this case, I want to keep the position of the middle div fixed as I scroll down ?

Adding `position: fixed` to `div3` css doesn't work.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zL8sc2a9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution #1**

You could use `flex` for this.

Wrap all div's in a container with `display: flex`:

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="div1">
    This is div 1
  </div>
  <div class="div3">
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    This is div 2
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
```

Let the `div1` and `div2` grow equally (remove widths, margins, paddings):

```css
.div1 {
  border-style: solid;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.div2 {
  border-style: solid;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Set a fixed width to the `div3`:

```css
.div3 {
  width: 18px;
}
```

That's it! Flex will do the trick for you: https://jsfiddle.net/1amuwfj5/

**Solution #2**

Use `calc()` to subtract `div3` width from `div1` and `div2`. General idea:

```css
.div1 {
  border-style: solid;
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% - 15px); /* we subtract 9x (half of div3) and 6px (border width) */
}
.div2 {
  border-style: solid;
  float: right;
  width: calc(50% - 15px);
}
.div3 {
  width: 18px;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/1amuwfj5/1/

Comment: Please see https://jsfiddle.net/78wrdh3u/4/             I have a button below div2. When the height of div1 and div2 is same, button div4 comes nicely to the right below div2 where it should be. But if the height of div2 increases, the button looses its position and moves to the middle.. I don't know how to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this adding a `div` around it and using `display: flex;`. Floating elements is really the old way to do this.

*Edit*
I updated the snippet to have the `.div3:after` fixed with scrolling.

```css
.page {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 150vh;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.div1 {
  border-style: solid;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: .5em;
}

.div2 {
  border-style: solid;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}

.div3:after {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f100";
  color: blue;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="div1">
      This is div 1
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
      This is div 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks promising. Ofcourse, my page is far more complex. Will give it a try. What if I want to add some space between left and right of div 3 ? Say a pixel. Is it possible with this?

Comment: Have edited the question. What if I want the position of the middle symbol fixed as I scroll down. How do I achieve that with flex?